# explanation of this c# definition: function_name(this class_name namevar)

Tags: c#

I was looking for information about this structure but I could't found it; so if someone have time to explain this or point to some URl where it's explained.

I found this definition at function sin web C# applications as for example:

```
  public static class PrincipalExtensions
{
    public static Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity SiteIdentity(this System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principal)
    {
       .....
       }

 }
```

Comment: [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an extension method. See the following article for detailed information : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Short version : this constructs enables you to make some methods available to be called on a class instance, even if you cannot (or do not) want to inherit from the class. It will not give you access to protected or private members/fields/methods.

Most notable usage : extension methods on IEnumerable / IQueryable in System.Linq namespace.

Comment: Also his question has a lot to do with ASP, hence the "Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity"

Comment: It's worth noting that it doesn't actually add methods to a class, it just provides syntax that makes it appear as if the method was added to the class. The method itself is just a static method, even when it's an extension method.  (While this doesn't seem meaningful, it really is significant.)

Answer (score 2):

This is an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) which returns an object of a custom type `Site.Web.Models.SiteIdentity`.

> A principal object represents the security context of the user on
>   whose behalf the code is running, including that user's identity
>   (IIdentity) and any roles to which they belong.